How to know what are the longest nodes in my website?
I want to know what are the longest nodes in my website, preferably by the number of bytes (just as the length of Wikipedia articles is commonly counted in their revision history page by bytes) but if there is no quick way in regards to bytes then any other plausible option is fine, number of words perhaps.
In my particular website all content types have just two fields: Body and Tags.
How to know what are the longest nodes in my website?

This is difficult to answer for a Drupal site if we don’t know the fields that are on your particular content types, although the internal page cache table could be used.

I have updated the question with a clarification just about that.

If you compare this to Wikipedia you probably input the content via CKEditor. Then you could write an SQL query using LENGTH() on the body field.
A good code example and a module you could use to display the longest nodes in a Views table is https://www.drupal.org/project/views_sort_length.
views_sort_length/src/Plugin/views/sort/Length.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\views_sort_length\Plugin\views\sort;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\sort\SortPluginBase;

/**
 * Sort handler for ordering by length of field.
 *
 * @ingroup views_sort_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsSort("views_sort_length")
 */
class Length extends SortPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $this->ensureMyTable();

    $this->query->addOrderBy(NULL, 'LENGTH(' . $this->tableAlias . '.' . $this->realField . ')', $this->options['order'], $this->field);
  }

}

